# Retrieve address of someone.. with iphone contacts picker

Tags: iphone, objective-c

From this method :`- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person`

How I can get the full street address + city + country and zipcode...

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Apple documentation:

ABRecordCopyValue
Returns the value of a record property.

```
CFTypeRef ABRecordCopyValue (
   ABRecordRef record,
   ABPropertyID property
);
```

Parameters

**record**

The record containing the property in question.

**property**

The property of record whose value is being returned. See properties in “Constants” in ABPerson Reference and “Constants” in ABGroup Reference.

**Return Value**

The value of property in record.

So you would just ask your ABRecord for the specific properties and you should be fine!

- const ABPropertyID kABPersonAddressProperty;
- const CFStringRef kABPersonAddressStreetKey;
- const CFStringRef kABPersonAddressCityKey;
- const CFStringRef kABPersonAddressStateKey;
- const CFStringRef kABPersonAddressZIPKey;
- const CFStringRef kABPersonAddressCountryKey;
- const CFStringRef kABPersonAddressCountryCodeKey;